# WordPress responsive images not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm building a custom theme for wordpress and it says responsive images are built into the wordpress core after wordpress 4.4+ but my images are not responsive. I've cleared my cache and tried it on my mobile phone but it still is not working.

here is my steps to an image:

In post image:

1. add media
2. select full size and insert into post
3. check inspect element: here is the code...

```html
<img class="size-full wp-image-28" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/picture1.jpg" alt="" width="1000" height="667" srcset="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/picture1.jpg 1000w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/picture1.jpg 600w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/picture1.jpg 768w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/picture1.jpg 30w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `width:100%` and `max-width:100%` to make it responsive, right now is not responsive because image has `height` and `width` attribute. if you need the only image will change into responsive use the auto generated class `wp-image-28`.

Css Part like

```
img.size-full {
   width:100% !important;
   max-width:100% !important;
}
```

**OR**

```
img.size-full.wp-image-28 {
   width:100% !important;
   max-width:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: check the height and width attribute still with your image ? if yes then this will not work. then check the themes option or classes to get that fixed.

Comment: wordpress 4.4+ should have responsive images by itself right?

Comment: Yes may the image class conflict with others you can google theme option to get it, i think

Comment: individualise the `width:100%` work fine. check it  https://jsfiddle.net/qzgpL0w6/, so you can get the solution by theme or help center of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px){
    .entry-content img{
        max-width:50%;
    }
}
```

Using this works, but if you have a long caption it will still mess up the padding/margin around the image.